# Неубиваемый сервис в текущих реалиях

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

Нужно сделать сервис который остаётся активным, даже если телефон находится в режиме ожидания. То есть заблокирован и лежит в кармане. Или телефон перезагрузился/выключился, сервис перезапустился. В сервисе использую alarmmanager который раз в минуту вызывает определённые методы(получение gps и отправка на сервер).  Но пока решил не торопится с сервисам как таковым. Может кто то уже сталкивался с подобным? Как обходили Doze Mode? Может есть примеры? Сейчас сервис написан так(пока даже не запускал): Запускается активность, нажимается кнопка, запускается сервис. В сервисе в oncreate вызывается alarmmanager и выполняет раз в минуту методы. Для предотвращения убийства используется:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    startService(new Intent(this, GpsService.class));
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    startService(new Intent(this, GpsService.class));
}
```

Верен ли сейчас подход? Или пока не поздно лучше делать иначе?
Дополняю свой вопрос. Администрация, если нужно создать новый то напишите пожалуйста.
Итак, дремота вроде как побеждена... Для получения координат использую следующее:

```
public void requsetLocationUpdate()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                locations = locationResult.getLocations();
                currentLat = locations.get(0).getLatitude();
                currentLon = locations.get(0).getLongitude();
            }
        }, Looper.myLooper());
    }
}
```

Вызываю его в OnStartComand. Предвидел что OnLocationResult поведёт себя так, а именно будет вызываться сам по себе не взирая ни на что... В методе OnCreate прописал следующее:

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000*60);
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000*60);
```

Сервис пробуждается по сигналу тревоги AlarmManager, вызывает метод requsetLocationUpdate() он работает как положено. Но потом вызывается ещё несколько раз и типо обновляет координаты. Выявил данный косяк с помощью отладчика android studio. Вижу такой выход: вызывать removelocationupdates после получения координат. Но тогда появляется проблема с синхронизацией потоков(Метод отправки координат на сервер вызывается в том же OnStartCommand естественно в потоке). В итоге происходит следующее, отправляются координаты полученные ранее, а новые просто висят, и отправятся в следующий раз. И всё по новой...

Comment: Не знаю на счёт рано или поздно. Но идея вовсе не впечатляет. Попахивает вирусом. Но это мое субъективное мнение

Comment: Куда там.... Это что то типо gps трекера. С утра включил приложение, ушёл. Всё это время телефон отправляет данные о местоположении на сервер. Вечером пришёл, будет например 480 записей, и каждую можно проанализировать

Comment: Так почему же нельзя выключить? Почему неубиваемый

Comment: Такие требования, не я придумал)

Comment: а с выключенным телефоном как быть?:) Но я бы пилил свой лаунчер, тогда шансов больше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще можно успеть в ваш поезд. Ориентируйтесь на API 29 (до осени это еще проходит). Вас интересует Foreground Service. Важное замечание, обязательно наличие видимого notification (оповещения), которое висит в шторке. Своему бизнесу попробуйте это обосновать, покажите примеры gps трекеров. Если будете работать с местоположением, вам необходимо разрешение android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION Это новое разрешение для доступа к местоположению в фоне, тема достойна отдельного вопроса.

Показываю вам пример кода, которые можно использовать. Для инъекции используется dagger 2.28.3

```kotlin
class EventRecorderService : LifecycleService() {

  // тут все ваши зависимости, обычно это livedata которая поставляет какие-то данные, например местоположение.

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        // подписываетесь и обрабатываете результат вашей livedata
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // создание того самого висящего в шторке оповещения
        val notification = NotificationHelper.trackingNotification(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0L))
            .build()
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        if (intent.action == null) {
            Timber.e("action was null, flags = $flags +  bits = ${Integer.toBinaryString(flags)}")
            return START_STICKY
        }

        when (intent.action) {
            KEY_START -> startTracking()
            KEY_STOP -> stopTracking()
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

private fun stopTracking() {
        // пример оставновки сервиса
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }

companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        private const val KEY_START = "START"
        private const val KEY_STOP = "STOP"

        fun start(context: Context) {
            sendAction(context, KEY_START)
        }

        fun stop(context: Context) {
            sendAction(context, KEY_STOP)
        }

        private fun sendAction(context: Context, action: String) {
            val intent = Intent(context, EventRecorderService::class.java)
            intent.action = action
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
        }

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        fun isRunning(context: Context): Boolean {
        // это проверка запущен ли сервис, могут быть отключены оповещения для вашего приложения, это нужно проверять
            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (EventRecorderService::class.java.name == service.service.className) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        @WorkerThread
        fun autoLaunchService(context: Context) {
            // тут некая логика запуска, которая решит стартовать сервис или нет
            start(context)
    }
}
```

autoLaunchService должен запускаться с некой переодичностью с помощью androidx.work.Worker, например вот так

```kotlin
fun enqueueServiceCheck() {
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG_SERVICE_CHECK)

        val worker = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ServiceCheckWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(TAG_SERVICE_CHECK)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(worker)
    }
```

Comment: Нужно ли мне раз в 15 минут вызывать work для запуска сервиса, если в onStart прописан start sticky?

Comment: И я не совсем понимаю как логику прописать для автозапуска... Допустим я могу опрашивать запущен сервис или нет, но если система просто убивает процесс и всё... Разве будет вызов ondestroy и т д?

Comment: @Domex действительно START_STICKY должен воссоздать ваш сервис. Возможно worker избыточен, но вы же хотите позаботиться об пользователях и одновременно подстраховаться? С помощью worker можно периодически запускать `autoLaunchService(context: Context)` в которой будет логика выключения сервиса в нерабочее время и включения в рабочее. Так вы сэкономите ресурсы устройства

Comment: вы были правы по поводу background location. Разрешение в манифесте есть, но когда устройство заблокировано новые координаты он получает не всегда. В основном у меня 5 раз одни и те же выводятся. Потом 1 раз изменятся и опять несколько одинаковых. Я использую  fusedlocationproviderclient.getlastlocation. Возможно поэтому... Ведь запроса на обновления нет. Вызывается получение новых координат через метод. Через коллбэки  не думаю что получится. Ловить их не хочется. Может быть есть шанс принудительно вызывать обновление и получение?

Comment: @Domex все верно, всеже попробуйте зарегестрировать LocationCallback(), переопределите метод onLocationResult(result: LocationResult?), если уж в него заходят одинаковые локации - запомите предыдущую и сравните. Если они одинаковые можете её пропустить. Я делаю это в liveData и когда у меня новая локация вызываю postValue(location).

Comment: А как он будет получать координаты если устройство дремлет? В том плане что по сигналу тревоги он вышел из дремоты, и сервис начнётся с onstartcommand. Как вызвать результ или апдейт жёстко, а не тогда когда он сам хочет? Я попробую сделать то что вы посоветовали. И задам новый вопрос. В случае если не удастся. Если удастся тоже задам, может кому то пригодится.

Comment: дополнил свой ответ. Описал некий костыль...

Answer (score 1):

https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/
только если так и только на API 29.
и то, если попадется оболочка Redmi MIUI, то ничего не поможет.

еще важным моментом в работе с фоновыми сервисами важно "есть ли запущенное Активити?"
поэтому рекомендую переписать кнопку "Назад" словно она является кнопкой "Домой".
приложение должно быть в состоянии onPause. это увеличит шансы "жизни" Сервиса.

Comment: Прочитал что можно "ослабить" Doze через настройку батареи. У меня есть возможность вообще отключить режим сна. Или же можно добавить приложения в "Белый список". Значит ли это, что я могу например раз в минуту если телефон заблокирован будить его, считывать координаты и отправлять? В документации конкретно про свой случай не нашёл, но нашёл вот что: Типо через час бездействия телефон переходит в режим standby, глушит все сервисы кроме системных, и слушает notify только с высоким приоритетом. Если нужно проделать какое то действие, то на это даётся около 10 сек. Переодичность 1 раз в 15 минут

Comment: @Domex а как вы его будить хотите? любимый AlarmManager уже давно не гарантирует даже "минутную точность" в Фоновых Сервисах.

Comment: Да....с фоновыми службами ща туговато... Вроде сервис написал, и он даже работает, ну во всяком случае система пока его не убила. Ща попробую подкинуть ему LocationManager. Остаётся только загвоздка с получением координат раз в 5 минут хотя бы. Планировщики сразу отметаю. У них минимальное время 15 минут. Смотрю в сторону handler, тоже планировщик если можно так выразится. Но не знаю как он себя поведёт когда устройство в режиме standby.

Comment: @Domex если вы просите у пользователя его координаты в фоновом сервисе, обязательно читайте ответ выше про android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION !
на handler современные Android'ы реагируют как и на Thread - негативно. т.е. если захотят - они их просто напросто убьют.
из своего опыта, когда вставал вопрос между Thread, Handler и AlarmManager, я выбрал Alarm. первых два - могут быть убиты и просто так не воскреснут.
а вот AlarmManager не убивали. ДА! начало его работы задерживалось от пары минут до 1,5 часа (плохой опыт с Redmi MIUI), но он жил.

Comment: @Domex и кстати... вы ведь можете, когда запрашиваете координаты указывать "интервал запроса" либо "запрос, когда пройдено N расстояние".
и где вы взяли, что "минимальные 15 мин для планировщиков"? у меня под API 29 все работает и при 1 минуте.

Comment: Я имел ввиду job scheduler и подобное. Background location в манифест я добавил...Сейчас получение координат сделал через fusedlocation. В аларме минимальное время 15 минут, я ставил 5 минут или минуту. Но в итоге получал координаты через 15. Но видимо ничего лучше я найти не смогу... разве что подобные ему. Тот же work например. Но остаётся ещё открытие http соединения. Как себя он поведет в standby, даже предположить не могу.

Comment: Я честно говоря уже запутаться начал с foreground и background. Если задача висит в фоне, пользователь её видит соответственно меньше шансов что система убьёт его. Если в back её помещать то что будет?) Или вы имеете ввиду проверку

Comment: А что если использовать power manager и ignorebatteryoptimizations?

Comment: @Domex честно, даже не отвечу. у меня есть полуживой проект с получение координат, но там "способ получения координат" ооооочень старый и древний. и вот там прописывалось "когда получать новые координаты (время или пройденное расстояние)?". но у меня это все сделано, только когда пользователь находится В приложении (без фона). и есть проект, в котором я делал длительный неубиваемый фоновый сервис. там это сделано через Foreground.

Comment: @Domex я думаю, что вам надо засунуть получение координат в Foreground сервис. дать пермиссион ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION (без него, по идеи, получение координат в фоне не будет работать вообще НИКАК).
а вот "переодичность получения координат", мне кажется, вы должны сделать без всяких таймеров, отложенных, алармов и тд. раньше была такая функция по дэфолту.
сейчас поищу гайд, по которому я делал, но он ооооочень старый.

Comment: В документации пишут что alarm сработает только в следующий период обслуживания. Чтобы решить этот вопрос, дословно: Если вам нужно установить сигнализацию, которая срабатывает во время сна, используйте setAndAllowWhileIdle() или setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). У них там даже график приложен перехода в standby. Для моей задачи он выглядит скверно... Вы наверно имеете ввиду locationlistener? Я с ним пытался сделать. выставил периодичность раз в 5 минут. 1 раз точку я получил, а чтобы получить во второй раз нужно чтобы mindistance изменился.

Comment: хотя, ведь если mindistance не изменился то и пользователь остался на месте... И должна будет отправится его предыдущая точка

Comment: @Domex да, я имел ввиду locationlistener. вот дистанция у меня хромала, а с "таймером" все +- работало. но опять таки... когда я читал документацию на это, там было в стиле "вы отправляете ЗАПРОСЫ при ваших условиях. ОТВЕТ же придет как только сможет. "
ну и это все было в реалях Активити, а не фонового сервиса. p.s. уже гружу архив на ЯДиск. мб вам поможет.

Comment: @Domex https://disk.yandex.by/d/hJkcDnnSEMkb3A надеюсь модеры не удалят и вам поможет.

Comment: Благодарствую, да хранит вас зелёный droid)